# How to create iPad Application in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ipad

I am new to iphone game development, i have recently install cocoas2d. But the problem i whenever i search it always result in iPhone game tutorials. I want my game to use iPad screen resolution.

Thanks
Inam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its same, just change TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY in project settings to ipad